# Build an email from a datatable with strings VB.NET

Tags: string, vb.net, email

I am running some code that is cross checking two sql tables and creating a datatable where there are inconsistencies in the list. I want to then loop through this datatable and build an email to be sent to specific people. I want the format of the email to essentially be a row with a part name, thickness, and material. As the code loops through the datatable it will add each line item to a string block and then put that into the email. I am having trouble with the string building part, I don't know how to build the string for the email.

```
  If dt.Rows.Count >= 1 Then
                        'send pester email to Chris Steven Gary
                        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                            Part = row.Item("PART_NUMBER")
                            Thickness = row.Item("Thickness")
                            Material = row.Item("SigmaNest_Material")

                            Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
                            Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()

                            Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = True
                            Smtp_Server.Port = 25
                            Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = False
                            Smtp_Server.Host = "email.email@email.com"

                            e_mail = New MailMessage()
                            e_mail.From = New MailAddress("email@email.com")
                            e_mail.To.Add("email@email.com, ")
                            e_mail.Subject = "Header"
                            e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
                            e_mail.Body = "Place string for parts list here"
                            Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
                        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try building your string in a loop something like this:

```
     dim the_part() as string = nothing
     dim thickness() as string = nothing
     dim material() as string = nothing

     For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
         the_part(row) = "Part = " & Cstr(row.Item("PART_NUMBER"))
         thickness(row) = "Thickness = " &  Cstr(row.Item("Thickness"))
         material(row) = "Material = " &  Cstr(row.Item("SigmaNest_Material"))
     Next

     Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
     Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
     Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
     Smtp_Server.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
     Smtp_Server.Port = 25
     Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = False
     Smtp_Server.Host = "domain_name.com"

     Dim the_list as string = Nothing

     For counter = 0 to the_part.count - 1
         the_list = the list & environment.newline & _
                    the_part(counter) & environment.newline & _
                    thickness(counter) & environment.newline & _   
                    material(counter) & environment.newline
     Next       

     With e_mail
            .From = New MailAddress("your_email@your_domain.com")
            .To.Add("email@domain.co.za")
            .Subject = "Something"
            .IsBodyHtml = False
            .Body = "Good day," & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & _
                    the_list &  & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & _
                    "Thank you"

    End With
    Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you shoud not put the 'Send' inside a loop, it will send several messages at once.

One way of reaching the desired output would be concatenating the string for each row data.

```
If dt.Rows.Count >= 1 Then
    Dim Header as string = "Part Number" & vbtab & "Thickness" & vbtab & "Material"
    Dim Data as string = string.empty
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Part = row.Item("PART_NUMBER")
        Thickness = row.Item("Thickness")
        Material = row.Item("SigmaNest_Material")
        Data = Data & if(not isDBNull(Part),Part,string.empty) & vbtab
        Data = Data & if(not isDBNull(Thickness ),Thickness ,string.empty) & vbtab
        Data = Data & if(not isDBNull(Material),Material,string.empty) & vbcrlf
    next

    Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
    Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()

    Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    Smtp_Server.Port = 25
    Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = False
    Smtp_Server.Host = "email.email@email.com"

    e_mail = New MailMessage()
    e_mail.From = New MailAddress("email@email.com")
    e_mail.To.Add("email@email.com, ")
    e_mail.Subject = "Header"
    e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
    e_mail.Body = "Place string for parts list here"
    Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
End if
```